# Logic: How to disable live microphone playback?

Tags: logic-pro

How do I get logic to stop doing a live playback of whatever the microphone hears?  I only have this problem in one project, but it's driving me nuts.  It interferes with recording, because there is a slight delay before the sound is played back.  I just want to turn it off.

Even when every track in the project is muted and nothing is being recorded, you can still hear sounds picked up by the microphone in the audio output.

Answer (score 1):

There is an “I” button next to the “R” record button, both in the track and on the channel strip. This is for input monitoring. If this is on then Logic will always play the input from that channel regardless of whether it’s armed for recording. This combined with direct monitor selected on your interface will mean your sound is being played from two sources at once and there’s usually a bit of latency on the DAW side.

When I record I use direct monitoring on my interface and make sure the “I” is deactivated. That way I am hearing my sound before it reaches Logic with no latency. However the “I” can be useful when punching combined with “auto input monitoring”. When in play mode you hear the original track and your instrument is silenced until the actual punch. It depends on how you like to work.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to turn Input Monitoring off for the audio track you are recording to. You can find the Input Monitoring button on the track in the Mixer; the button has an "I" on it. Open the Mixer by pressing "X".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Even with no tracks armed or live the mic could still pick up the room.  It turned out that somehow I must have created an Aux track and that’s where it was routed to. When I brought up the mixer I could see the levels reacting on that Aux track. The issue was resolved after I deleted that track.